# Translating "order of protection and conservation"

Tags: verbs, english-to-latin-translation, motto, derivation, genitive

An author friend recently asked me for help with a Latin name: in his book, a group calls itself the "order of protection and conservation", but in Latin to be pretentious (*altum videtur…*).

My immediate thought was *ōrdō prōtectiōnis cōnservātiōnisque*:

- *ōrdō* for this sort of "order" is well-attested, both classically and in modern times
- *prōtegō* is a fine word for "protect" but *dēfendō* and *tūtor* work just as well, I'll ask which he likes the best
- *cōnservō* is straightforwardly "conserve" and I can't think of any other Latin verb for that

However, I'm not at all certain about using a verbal noun in the genitive for this. Latin generally likes participles and gerunds and the like where English would use a verbal noun. Is there a better grammatical construction for this sort of thing, attested either classically or later?

Answer (score 3):

Classical Latin sometimes uses a gerundive dative to express the purpose of an administrative unit, such as various kinds of [*decemviri*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decemviri).
The linked Italian Wikipedia article lists *decemviri legibus scribundis consulari imperio*, *decemviri stlitibus iudicandis*, *(quin)decemviri sacris faciundis*, and *decemviri agris dandis adsignandis*.
I read this dative as "a committee appointed for the purpose of".

If you use something like this, then you need an object: What are they protecting and conserving?
Assuming it's the republic, I would suggest ***ordo rei publicae defendendae et conservandae***.
If the group happens to consist of fixed number of men, then *decemviri* with some number is a possible choice.

If you don't want to go with datives, then I would suggest adjectives.
Somehow ***ordo protectivus conservativusque*** sounds better to me than the genitives of verbal nouns.
Such use of adjectives is attested in *triumviri monetales* and *praetor peregrinus*.
I also came across a genitive, but more in the spirit of my earlier dative examples than your construction: *quattuorviri viarum curandarum*.

I recommend using gerundives or adjectives.
Perhaps the gerundives are more free of English connotations, as *conservativus* might make people think of "conservative" instead of "conservation".
The two concepts are obviously related, but they have a different tone.